# how to make main thread wait for executor service threads to complete

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Here is my main thread , inside each process i am calling executor service threads. At line 4 , before updating the status  , i want to wait for my all threads to complete

```
 line 1- missingStrategyContext.process(FileType.CARD, programId, fromDate, toDate, channel);
 line 2- missingStrategyContext.process(FileType.TRANSACTION, programId, fromDate, toDate, channel);
 line 3- missingStrategyContext.process(FileType.REFUND, programId, fromDate, toDate, channel);

 line 4- processingLog.setProcessingStatus(TransactionState.SUCCESS.name());
```

Inside each process i am deciding on file type value which strategy i have to call

```
public void process(FileType fileType, String programId, Long fromDate, Long toDate, String channel){
    map.get(fileType).process(programId, fromDate, toDate, channel, fileType);
}
```

and then depending on file type i have implemented my process method and called executor service in each file type implementation

```
@Override
public void process(String programId, Long fromDate, Long toDate, String channel, FileType fileType) {

    MultiTenantTxMgmt multiTenantTxMgmt = MultiTenantTxMgmtUtil.get(programId);
    EntityManager entityManager = null;

    List<MissingReason> reasonList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        entityManager = multiTenantTxMgmt.getEntityManager();
        reasonList = missingDataRepository.getDistinctMissingReasonForFileType(entityManager, fileType, TransactionState.READYTOATTEMPT);
    }catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw new UnkownBatchSaveException();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    reasonList.forEach(
            missingReason -> deExecutorService.dotask(() ->
                    missingTransactionStrategyContext.processMissingV3(missingReason, programId, fromDate, toDate, channel, fileType)
            )
    );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CountDownLatch#await`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Eg copied from docs:

```
CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(N);

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // create and start threads
    new Thread(new Worker(startSignal, doneSignal)).start();

doSomethingElse();            // don't let run yet
startSignal.countDown();      // let all threads proceed
doSomethingElse();
doneSignal.await();           // wait for all to finish
```

Comment: but I am calling multiple executorservice from line 1, line 2 , line 3 . at line 4 i want to know , whether all executor threads completed or not , so do I need to take countdown in each method

Comment: Start the countdown with 4 and invoke `ob.countDown();` in each. It will do the trick. @MuddassirRahman

Answer (score 0):

You could make `doTask` method let return a (completable) future (if it does not already) and return a list of futures in method `process`, e.g. replace

```
reasonList.forEach(
            missingReason -> deExecutorService.dotask(() ->
                    missingTransactionStrategyContext.processMissingV3(missingReason, programId, fromDate, toDate, channel, fileType)
            )
    );
```

with

```
    final List<Future> futures = reasonList.stream()
        .map(missingReason -> deExecutorService.dotask(() ->
            missingTransactionStrategyContext
                .processMissingV3(missingReason, programId, fromDate, toDate, channel, fileType)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

  }
return futures;
```

Then in your calling part you can wait on all these futures to terminate before continuing.

Comment: I used Countdownlatch and it worked for me, may be this i can try in future